# Firestore Cloud Functions to trigger sms

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, twilio, google-cloud-functions

I have the following cloud function that will trigger a sms message to be sent using Twillio. It works as is but it causes the text message to be sent twice. Is there a way I can modify my function to prevent this? Please note that I am not using the Firebase Realtime Database; I am using the Firebase Firestore Database. This function is being used in conjunction with an Ionic 4 project.

```
export const textPrayedForNotification = functions.firestore.document('/prayerRequests/{prayerRequestId}').onUpdate(snap => {
    const phone: string = snap.after.get('phoneNumber');
    const receiveNotifications: boolean = snap.after.get('receiveNotifications');

    if (receiveNotifications) {
        return client.messages.create({
            to: phone,
            from: twilioNumber,
            body: 'Someone has prayed for you.'
        }).then((data: any) => {
            console.log(data);
        }).catch((error: any) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
});
```

Update:
Change function to this and now it seems to work.

```
export const textPrayedForNotification = functions.firestore.document('/prayerRequests/{prayerRequestId}').onUpdate(snap => {
    const phone: string = snap.after.get('phoneNumber');
    const receiveNotifications: boolean = snap.after.get('receiveNotifications');
    const dateLastPrayedBefore = snap.before.get('dateLastPrayed');
    const dateLastPrayedAfter = snap.after.get('dateLastPrayed');

    if (receiveNotifications) {
        if (dateLastPrayedBefore !== dateLastPrayedAfter) {
            return client.messages.create({
                to: phone,
                from: twilioNumber,
                body: 'Someone has prayed for you.'
            }).then((data: any) => {
                console.log(data);
            }).catch((error: any) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you know if the document is getting updated quickly in succession? You can compare `snap.before` and `snap.after` to see if something changed. What does your data model look like and what update (client-side) is supposed to trigger this?

Comment: It is triggered when an updated date is written to the database.

Comment: Does the function actually execute twice, or is Twilio just sending two messages somehow?

Comment: @jdubicki What I was really getting at is I think it would be helpful for us to see what the data model is like a bit more specifically :)